# jaxb, external binding of attribute of a given element

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to coerce the xjc compiler to produce code that will allow me to bind a set of accessor methods to an attribute of an element.

For example the schema contains:

```
   <xsd:complexType name="HostInfo">
         <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Host configuration </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:attribute name="hostInfoId" type="svtosz:UUID" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute name="mgmtServerId" type="svtosz:UUID" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute name="hostInfoType" type="svtosz:HostInfoType"
            use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

     ....
          <xsd:element name="hostInfo" type="svtosz:HostInfo"
```

How do I reference the hostInfoId attribute of the hostInfo element in an external binding file?

I have tried (beaucoup) variations of:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="1.0">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="hostInformation.xsd" >
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='hostInfo']/@hostInfoId">
        <jxb:property>
            <jxb:baseType>
                <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String"
                    parseMethod="HostId.parseHostId" printMethod="HostId.printHostId" />
            </jxb:baseType>
        </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

Alas there has been no joy in Mudville. I also tried to set up a binding for the base type svtos:UUID, but gave up on that. That type is declared in a separate XSD file that is included by the main XSD schema file.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

--Eric

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='hostInfo']/xs:attribute[@name='hostInfoId']">
```

Instead of

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='hostInfo']/@hostInfoId">
```